# FlashDevelop - browser crashes while FD is attached to Flash 11 debugger

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I've just upgraded to publish my SWF files as Flash 11.  I want to attach FlashDevelop to Firefox (or IE).  I'm able to first attach it, however player crashes after my first call to PHP file(not sure if it is related) and the debugger is stopped.  If I just run the program without debugging it doesn't crash.

How can I figure out what is causing the problem?

Here is my set up:

- FlashDevelop 4.0.1 RTM on Windows 7 (32bit)
- Installed - Windows Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content
  debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers) (EXE, 3.89MB) from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
- In FlashDevelop, I point `Program->Settings->FlashViewer` to flashplayer_11_plugin_debug_32bit.exe  (I'm not exactly sure if this correct).

The way I attach is by going to `Debug->Start Remote Session`.  Then launch an HTML page that loads my SWF.

**update:** Instead of upgrading to 11.2 version I upgraded to 11.1 .  Now I'm getting some feedback in the output window.  `[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` However  FlashDevelop doesn't break on that exception and I don't see a file name or line number which would help me to figure out wher exectly the error is happening.

**update:** I finally rolled back to my original version of 10.1.102.64  and now FlashDeveloper isn't crashing while debugging.

Comment: Out of curiousity, I wonder what would happen if you tried an earlier release of Flash 11? Flash 11.2 has major changes to how video is processed, and I've been noticing a lot of plugin crashes since 11.2 came out, particularly in Chrome.

Comment: Instead of debugger, does it also crash when simply the player runs.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani  it doesn't crash when I'm not debugging.

Comment: So, that can mean that debugger is giving out complex/looped runtime errors. You can better, trace and handle those runtime errors first and then can see if debugger crashes again.

Comment: @SunilD. I upgraded to 11.1 instead of 11.2 and I'm getting same behavior but now with more output.  I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug a flash application, you freeze the thread and your browser will think the application has locked up or died. It will then try to save your browsing session by force closing the plugin causing the problem (in this case, Flash).

To stop Firefox from doing this, type in "about:config" (minus quotes) in the address bar and hit enter, then click "I'll be careful" if a warning comes up.

Look for "dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs" by typing it in the config search bar and set its value to -1. This will stop the browser from shutting down laggy plugins.

Comment: Did that, I"m still having a problem. The thing is, it doesn't take for FlashDevelop and Flash player to connect.  There isn't a long wait and the crash happens almost as soon as I press a button inside of application.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the flash debugger plugin in your browser. Are you accessing the same SWF from the browser that you are debugging?

Comment: Which flash debugger plug-in are you referring to? The flash player debug plugin? Don't I need it in order to debug it?  Yes I'm accessing same SWF from the browser that I'm debugging, I'm able to hit a break point at one point and then it crashes.

Comment: I was under the impression that the IDE directly accesses the debugger plugin itself. So my idea for the issue was that you're spawing two of the same debugging sessions, one in the browser you're opening and the one running in flash developer which is causing the issue. Disabling it in your browser as a plugin will not disable flashdevelop from using it.